# Strange case of missing '&'

Tags: ms-access-2007

HI I have as my caption the company name which includes '&'

```
OURCOMPANY MEDICAL & DENTAL CARE INC.
```

instead of displaying the stated caption it does this:

```
OURCOMPANY MEDICAL .DENTAL CARE INC.  it has some kind of character instead if the '&'  like a short '-'
```

this is the code from the caption of the report. But when it prints, it leaves out the '&'. This is happening in 2 locations both do not display the '&'.

Is there any reason that you can think of?

Comment: It is probably a tine underlined space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The & is the escape character for shortkeys. So use:

```
OURCOMPANY MEDICAL && DENTAL CARE INC.
```